# iOS - malloc Is there any virtualization

Tags: ios

Say I have X bytes of free RAM on my iOS device
I do a malloc of X+1 bytes

Will I always fail?

Is there are any virtualization?

Sorry if this is stupid question - no flames please!

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't see a problem with mallocing in small doses for performance intensive purposes, but my question would be why could you possibly want to malloc all the free ram, and not only what you need?

Answer (score 0):

According to [iPhone OS Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf), yes, it will fail and no, you can't use virtual memory. Check pg 130, The Virtual Memory System.

Comment: To be more clear: it may not fail if it can take other apps away from memory, but eventually it will fail when it has no more code to unload.

Comment: Thanks - My question really was - can you use virtual memory during malloc and looks like the answer is NO.